How are Fermionic and vector valued quantum field theories rigorously defined?
A scalar (spin 0) quantum field is rigorously defined as an operator valued distribution. By Wick rotating to Euclidean space we can view a quantum field theory as a measure over distributions. How much of this transfers over to quantum fields describing particles with nonzero spin?
For Fermionic theories I know we must use a Grassmann algebra because of the anticommunitivity of the fields, but what does this mean in terms of a rigorous definition? Are these theories still operator valued distributions? Is the measure still over a space of distributions? Are these measures Grassmann valued?
Similarly for Bosonic theories of nonzero spin (i.e. vector fields) what does it mean to have a quantum field? How is the vector nature of these fields accounted for in the measure or as an operator valued distribution?
